# Selected tab in TabLayout is not shown on screen after returning to app

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am using `ViewPager2` along with `TabLayout` and `TabLayoutMediator` to display some fragments.
I have a problem when I leave the app (for example by tapping the home button) and then open it again, the `TabLayout` jumps to some other tabs. The correct tab, i.e. the last one the user was on when he left the app, is still selected and the correct fragment is still shown. It's just the tabs layout that gets scrolled to an unrelated position for some reason.

What can be the problem?

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserItemsViewModel.class);

    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new ItemListFragmentAdapter(requireActivity(), mType));
    tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
            (tab, position) -> {
                if (position == 0) {
                    tab.setText("All");
                } else {
                    tab.setText(((ItemListFragmentAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter()).getItemAt(position - 1).getName());
                }
            }
    );

    mViewModel.getFormatsLD().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<FormatItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<FormatItem> formatItems) {
            ItemListFragmentAdapter adapter = (ItemListFragmentAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
            if (adapter != null) {
                ((ItemListFragmentAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter()).setItems(formatItems);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    tabLayoutMediator.attach();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, false);


}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    currentPage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    tabLayoutMediator.detach();
}
```

`currentPage` is a field in the parent fragment which hosts the `ViewPager2` and `TabLayout` which is used to retain the last tab/page the user was on when the fragment got paused.

You can see in these photos below how it looks before leaving the app and after returning to it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the problem lies in .attach() and .detach(), only detach **onDestory()**

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot of the before and after? because "The correct tab...still selected... just the tabs layout that gets scrolled to an unrelated position" is not clear. if the right tab is selected whats the problem

Comment: @Ali I will give it a go. I detached because of some other problem I had, which I think moving the detaching to ```onDestroy()``` may make it come back. But i'll try.

Comment: @m'hdsemps I will upload a photo.

Comment: @tfreifeld ok mate let me know if you get stuck

Comment: @Ali, that did it! I removed ```detach()``` from ```onPause()```, and moved ```attach()``` to ```onViewCreated()``` and it works now as needed, and it seems no other problem has returned (I had quite a few around this setup, and I checked all of them, and hopefully I haven't missed anything). 
Thank you very much!

Do I ought to to add ```detach()``` to ```onDestroy()```? Or does things "take care of themselves" when destroying the fragment and its object?

Comment: It is not necessary to detach on destroying because garbage collection automatically does so, but it is considered to be good practice to clean you mess :D, please upvote the comment and mark this question as answered, or should i write the Anser so that every one could see ?

Comment: I've added the answer so that every person who gets the problem could see this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove `.detach()` and `.attach()` from on pause and move `.attach()` to `onCreateView()`**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, false);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    currentPage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
}
```

**it's not necessary because garbage collection automatedly does so, but itconsidered as best practice**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    tabLayoutMediator.detach();
}
```